# How can I find elements containing a specific string by xpath in php?

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, behat

for an automatic test I want checkboxes of the rows containing a specific string to be checked.
when I search elements by xpath in the console, it finds exactly the elements I want, but when I run the tests it checks all the checboxes, no matter if they contain that string.

I think the problem lies in the function:

```
public function iCheckCheckboxInRowsWith($col){

    $checkboxes = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findAll(
selector:'xpath',    
    sprintf('//table/tbody/tr[td[contains(text(), %s)]]/td/input[@type="checkbox"]',
    $col));    
    dump($checkboxes);    
    foreach( $checkboxes as $checkbox){    
        $checkbox->click();
    }

}
```

In terminal I see that the array  $checkboxes (which I have dumped) consists of all checkboxes.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try with following XPath. It may works.

```
sprintf('//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), %s)]/input[@type="checkbox"]', $col)
```

or try with following

```
sprintf('//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(., %s)]/input[@type="checkbox"]', $col)
```

Comment: still not working. I think the Xpath is correct. but the function doesn't take it as filter.

Comment: is it clicking all checkboxes still?

Comment: try with second one. It may works. please check my updated answer. Use .(dot) instead of text()

Comment: with the socond version it doesn't check any of them. and in the console it doesn't find the element either.

Comment: I think the problem is not the xpath, but the definition of $checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sprintf("//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(., '" +col+ "')]/input[@type='checkbox']"));
```

Comment: it doesn't work. as I mentioned before, the problem is not the xpath but the definition of $checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

although I had in annotation declared that $col is a string, I still had to put %s in quotion marks, so:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), "%s")]/preceding::td[1]/input[@type="checkbox"]
```